# Windows 8.1 Universal app WebClient substitution

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am migrating Win8 app to Win universal apps and I need to substitute following code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();                
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(URL));
```

Problem is, it seems WebClient is deprecated and is not supported anymore in universal apps. Someone recommended me HttpClient, but it has not suitable properties. Is there any compatible class I can use?

Comment: You should be able to use HttpClient.GetStringAsync instead.

Comment: @JakobChristensen Yes, I can download data string this way, but HttpClient has no events I can use. And I dont know any other way how to solve this. It is essential to call method after download is complete, but while this operation is async, I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I found is to use HttpClient class. Then manually check and process response message.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
string ResponceResult= await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/datalist.aspx"));
```

Answer (score -3):

use **`WebView`**

```
WebView wView;

wView.Navigate(new URI("page"))
wView.NavigationCompleted += new EventHandler(...)
wView.NavigationStarting  += new EventHandler(...)
```

Comment: WebView is for showing HTML. That's not what WebClient is for.